# Как учитывать погрешность при вычислениях значения функции

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы, ряды

Задается x и задается некая погрешность, например, 0,001. Моя погрешность вычисления функции не должна превышать заданную.  Как мне учитывать это при вычислениях?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    int x;
    double epsilon;
    std::cout << "Input x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Input epsilon: ";
    std::cin >> epsilon;
    double sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + ((pow(i, x))/(i*fact(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: ряд не сходится у вас. перепутали `i^x` => надо `x^i`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Почему же не сходится? вполне сходится, x ведь константа...

Comment: Я, бы тогда предложил точный ответ . @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вы имеете в виду - в аналитическом виде? что-то у меня пока навскидку никаких идей, как этот ряд считается...

Answer (score 4):

Обычно в таком случае, как у вас - для быстросходящегося ряда - принимают как оценку отбрасываемый член. Так что вам нужно прекращать считать, когда добавляемый член по абсолютной величине станет меньше погрешности.

В случае знакопеременного сходящегося ряда с монотонно убывающими по абсолютной величине членами такая оценка *точная*, в случае знакопостоянного могут быть нюансы...

В любом случае не рекомендовал бы считать вот так -

```
((pow(i, x))/(i*fact(i)));
```

нет смысла считать настолько неэффективно. Намек: рассмотрите отношение двух соседних членов ряда...